# How to unzip lists in lists in a list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
data = [ [[a,b],[a,d]], [[e,f],[g,h]], [[i,j],[k,j]] ]
```

And I want to unzip it so I have:

```
[[a,a], [e,g], [i,k]] and [[b,d], [f,h], [j,j]]
```

Along the same line, is there a way to get the length of list, without counting duplicates based on one value?  For example, using the first list above, I want to count the number of lists in each sublist, without counting duplicates in the second value.  So I want to get:

```
[2, 2, 1]
```

I'm able to get a result of [2, 2, 2] using:

```
count = [len(i) for i in data]
```

but since I can't separate the values, there is no way to check for duplicates in the second value alone.

Comment: are you trying to flatten your list and count the occurrences? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = [ [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]] ]
>>> list(zip(*[list(zip(*x)) for x in d]))
[((1, 3), (5, 7), (9, 11)), ((2, 4), (6, 8), (10, 12))]
```

Or with your example:

```
>>> d = [[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['i', 'j'], ['k', 'j']]]
>>> list(zip(*[list(zip(*x)) for x in d]))
[(('a', 'a'), ('e', 'g'), ('i', 'k')), (('b', 'd'), ('f', 'h'), ('j', 'j'))]
```

As for your counting, since you only want to look at the second values, you can just filter those out, create a set of them to get rid of duplicate values and then count them:

```
>>> [len(set(x[1] for x in y)) for y in d]
[2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I basically want to count the number of lists inside each list.  Right now, each list has two lists inside it (ex,[ [1,2] ,[3,4] ] would give 2).  However, I would like duplicates in the second value to not be counted. (ex. [ [1,2], [3,2] ] would give 1).

Also...I understand what should be happening in the code, but i'm getting an error "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack"

Answer (score 0):

To transpose your sublists:

```
data = [ [["a","b"],["a","d"]], [["e","f"],["g","h"]], [["i","j"],["k","j"]] ]

a,b = (map(list,zip(*(map(list, zip(*sub)) for sub in data))))

print(a,b)
[['a', 'a'], ['e', 'g'], ['i', 'k']] [['b', 'd'], ['f', 'h'], ['j', 'j']]
```

To get the counts you could use a set:

```
print([len(set(map(itemgetter(1), sub)) )for sub in data])

[2, 2, 1]
```

A set won't work for more than two sublists i.e:

```
data = [[["a", "b"], ["a", "d"]], [["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]], [["i", "j"], ["k", "j"], ["A", "K"], ["B", "K"]]]

from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

print([sum(v == 1 for v in Counter(map(itemgetter(1), sub)).values()) for sub in data])
[2, 2, 0]
```

If you used a set with the last data you would get `[2, 2, 2]` which I imagine would be wrong as there are no unique values

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't use map or list comprehension but is straightforward with just for loops.

```
data = [ [[a,b],[a,d]], [[e,f],[g,h]], [[i,j],[k,j]] ]

zip0 = []
zip1 = []
sub0=[]
sub1=[]

for x in data:
    for y in x:
        sub0.append(y[0])
        sub1.append(y[1])
    zip0.append(sub0)
    zip1.append(sub1)
    sub0 = []
    sub1 = []

print zip0
print zip1
```